# change date format on print page using window.print - javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

there is any way to do it?
I know user can change this in his settings, but there is any way to change this in code?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: this is not what I meant. I need to change the date on the header of the printed page

Comment: what do you mean by printing on the header page?

Comment: Referring to the format of the date that appears on the printed page. Good Valid Question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS **Date type** - Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

It can convert any date string to a specific locale. Or you can use its methods to build your own output.

```
Date d = new Date(dateString); //your current date as string
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('en-US')); //for example US locale
```

Comment: this is not what I meant. I need to change the date on the header of the printed page